# I want to serialize JSON from array to object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, serialization

This is my desired JSON format

```
{ "ReferId": "9800", 
"DestinationList":["250"], 
"EmailAddress": "Test_Emails@gmail.com", 
"ApplicantList":[ 
{
"FirstName":"Test", 
"LastName":"Test", 
"Dob":"01/01/1990", 
"Gender":"M", 
} ], 
"CreditCard": { 
"CardExpirationMonth": 1, 
"CardExpirationYear": 2021, 
"CardHolderAddress1": "123 Main", 
"Transaction": {"Amount":106.56} 
} 
}
```

Following this structure I've created the Model. Please find the class

```
public class Atlas_Purchase
    {
        public string ReferId { get; set; }
        public List<string> DestinationList { get; set; }
        public List<AtlasApplicantList> ApplicantList { get; set; }
        private List<AtlasCreditCardDetails> CreditCards = new List<AtlasCreditCardDetails>();
        public List<AtlasCreditCardDetails> CreditCard
        {
            get { return CreditCards; }
            set { CreditCards = value; }
        }

public class AtlasApplicantList
    {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class AtlasCreditCardDetails
    {
        public string CardExpirationMonth { get; set; }
        public string CardExpirationYear { get; set; }
        public string CardHolderAddress1 { get; set; }
        private List<AtlasTransaction> Transactions = new List<AtlasTransaction>();
        public List<AtlasTransaction> Transaction
        {
            get { return Transactions; }
            set { Transactions = value; }
        }
    }
```

But When I serialize the data and I'm getting the JSON in this format Incorrect JSON Structure

[image: Incorrect JSON Structure]

I have tried different ways to serialize the data but still no luck, please help to to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Biswarup

Comment: You have declared "Credit" property as List<AtlasCreditCardDetails>, therefore the deserialized object is going to be a list. isn't it? If you are going to have only one Credit property, it has to be defined as  **AtlasCreditCardDetails** not **List<AtlasCreditCardDetails>** and the same for "Transction" object ....

Comment: Get a sample JSON, edit your question and add the sample JSON to your question. Once you are done your question will be much easier to reproduce

Comment: Please find the json which is generate after applying the serialize
{
"ReferId": "9800",
"DestinationList":["250"],
"EmailAddress": "Test_Emails@gmail.com",
"ApplicantList":[
{"FirstName":"Test",
"LastName":"Test",
"Dob":"01/01/1990",
"Gender":"M",
}
],
"CreditCard": [{
 "CardExpirationMonth": 1,
 "CardExpirationYear": 2021,
 "CardHolderAddress1": "123 Main",
 "Transaction": [{"Amount":106.56}]
 }]
}

Comment: @Zadeh
as I've mentioned that the desired JSON having multiple values under AtlasCreditCardDetails, so I did in this way. Do you think I need to change the structure of the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AtlasTransaction { public decimal Amount {get;set;} }
```

Do you have this class ? 
Also instead of this code

```
private List<AtlasCreditCardDetails> CreditCards = new List<AtlasCreditCardDetails>();
public List<AtlasCreditCardDetails> CreditCard
{
get { return CreditCards; }
set { CreditCards = value; }
}
```

write this much only     `public List<AtlasCreditCardDetails> CreditCard {get;set;}`

same way change in class      `AtlasCreditCardDetails`     for property     `Transaction`

Comment: I've applied your logic, but no luck still getting response on the same format..

Comment: How about AtlasTransaction Class, do you have it ?

Comment: Also use `[JsonObject("CreditCard")]` over `AtlasCreditCardDetails`. You have to put also on another classes too because your class names are different from Json Objects. Add this attribute for `AtlasApplicantList,AtlasTransaction `